# How to check actual type of a union type in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, typechecking, union-types

I am making the following function call:

```
const page : (Nft | null)[] = await metaplex.nfts().findAllByMintList(mintAddressPage);
```

Which returns a type of `(Nft | null)[]`. I want to be able to check that `page` is in fact of type `Nft[]` before further operations are performed on it. How can I make it so that `page` has type `Nft[]` only after the check passes successfully?

Comment: `page` doesn't have a union type, it is an array of a union type. Did you mean you want to make sure it is `Nft[]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to use [predicates](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) to filter your array :

```
const maybePages: (Nft | null)[] = await metaplex.nfts().findAllByMintList(mintAddressPage);

const pages = maybePages.filter((page: Nft | null): page is Nft => page !== null)
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAcgZsKBeKBvAvgWAFA4MYD2AdgM6IC2AhiAEYQAKlA5hCQFxQAU8iAPlEQCuAG2EBKANoBdZFEoB3SgEsKEYJTDCIADwB0RBCU5jdcJUQAmAQVEAhEAFlzwADJKyncs6sWLAJ1YSRhYxAG4cfGIyKDBmVlkqWgY4klMlYWAIP05OWJYOHih%20IVExDjzod1gEZAA%20GLioAEIkFBLxCOwgA)